# Get access to a object over a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get access to a object over a variable. I´ve a object saved in lang that looks like that:

```
{TeamspeakControl: "Teamspeak Control"}
```

Now I want to get the string out over a variable like:

```
console.log(lang["TeamspeakControl"]);
```

If I run this now I get the error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TeamspeakControl' of undefined

Has someone a idea?

```js
var lang = {TeamspeakControl: "Teamspeak Control"};
$('lang').each(function() {
  console.log(lang[$(this).attr('label')]);
  $(this).html(lang[$(this).attr('label')]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/dist/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
<lang label="TeamspeakControl"></lang>
```

There it works. Looks like my get is async and is to slow. This is how my lang object will be filled.

```
    var lang = Object();
    $.get('lang', function(data) {
        lang = data;
    });
```

Comment: Right now you just have a _string_, not an object - you need to _decode_ the JSON first.

Comment: Then you have a typo somewhere as the example you gave works.

Comment: Yes it´s a Object. I´ve access if I write lang.TeamspeakControl. I write fast a jsfiddle....

Comment: seems like `lang` is out of scope, otherwise this code should work just fine.

Comment: ok then, where are you accessing the object?

Comment: It´s comming from nodejs express: app.get('/lang', function(req,res){
 res.send(packageLanguage);
});

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works, if I make it asynchronous like this:

```
    $.get('lang', function(data) {
        var lang = data;
        $('lang').each(function() {
            $(this).html(lang[$(this).attr('label')]);
        });
    });
```

But is that a good solution?

Answer (score -1):

Strange... It works for me:

```js
var lang = {TeamspeakControl: "Teamspeak Control"};
console.log(lang["TeamspeakControl"]);
```

In general, you're doing right, you only have to pay attention that you assign object to variable in same scope where you run `console.log`.

In your case you can `console.log` only inside callback even it's slow:

```
var lang = Object();
$.get('lang', function(data) {
    lang = data;
    console.log(lang);
});
```